# How to get rid of UV-unwrap distortions on a curved object (sock model)?

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

I needed to have image patterns placed on the sock to generate a bunch of sock renders. So I made a model and got these strange distortions on UV-unwrap on the ankle level.

I tried to fix that in different ways by adding more or fewer seams, by pinning the vertices, but it still doesn't work and I keep getting this odd result on the ankles.

This is the best result I got so far -  by making the UV match square shapes, adding the seam on the back, two seams around the feet, and one on the toes level.

I would really appreciate a piece of advice from fellow modelers since I don't know how to go any further :)

The third image shows the default UV unwrap.

[image]
[image: screenshot]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work for me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Use the UV sculpt tool to tweak stuff around to minimize distortion.

No matter what though you're going to have to compromise somewhere. Either things will be super perfectly aligned to your texture but slightly distorted in places, or vice versa. It's always gonna be a struggle trying to fit UVs to a preexisting texture. Especially one with such a distinct pattern like that.

I would look also consider looking at actual reference of some knit socks and try to follow the seams that they put in there. See if that works better. I did try it but couldn't get anything I liked. Keep in mind a lot of time when it looks "bad/not realistic" it's just because you're winging it when knit socks actually follow a strict pattern.